# Why does WatchService use unbound wildcard WatchEvent<?> rather than WatchEvent<Path>

Tags: java, watchservice

I just followed this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to use the `WatchService` API. I have no idea about why 
using `WatchEvent<?>` rather than `WatchEvent<Path>`, if I use the latter one, no need to cast, or there is any other situations that the `WatchService` can use to monitor **non-Path events**?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
    return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
}

void processEvents() {
    for (; ; ) {
        ...
        //why doesn't the poolEvents() return WatchEvent<Path> 
        for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

            ...

            //here he use a static method cast() to SuppressWarnings the unchecked warning
            WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadoc of [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) says:

> File systems may report events faster than they can be retrieved or processed and an implementation may impose an unspecified limit on the number of events that it may accumulate. Where an implementation knowingly discards events then it arranges for the key's pollEvents method to return an element with an event type of OVERFLOW. This event can be used by the consumer as a trigger to re-examine the state of the object.

[StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardWatchEventKinds.html#OVERFLOW) is of type `WatchEvent.Kind<Object>`, which I believe is why pollEvents needs to return a List of `WatchEvent<?>` rather than `WatchEvent<Path>`. The Javadoc for OVERFLOW also mentions:

> The context for this event is implementation specific and may be null

which is why the type of the overflow event needs to be `WatchEvent<Object>`.

Note that the tutorial that you linked suggests the following:

> Retrieve the type of event by using the kind method. No matter what events the key has registered for, it is possible to receive an OVERFLOW event. You can choose to handle the overflow or ignore it, but you should test for it.

You should therefore add the following to your code (if you haven't already):

```
if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
    continue;
}
```